Problem when trying to get Sector Market Cap
In finance as I am learning we have Sectors and within the Sectors we have Industries.
I am trying to get the Market Cap through the yfinance API through the following code:
import yfinance as yf
tech = yf.Sector('technology')
software = yf.Industry('software-infrastructure')
print(tech.overview)

But the answer is:

AttributeError: module 'yfinance' has no attribute 'Sector'`

May it be related with yfinance API instead of my usage?
I am applying what's written in the documentation.

Where did you get yfinance?  What version is it?  What version of Python?  It has been a fairly dynamic package as Yahoo changes its rules periodically.

The yfinance version I had was "0.2.40" I've just upgraded it to the newest that is "0.2.50" and it worked!
Lesson: When the documentation says something, just checkout if your package is the most updated, just passed by me.
Much appreciated your time Tim!

It seems that I was working with a deprecated yfinance version.
I've solved it by upgrading the package through the command "pip install --upgrade yfinance" as Tim raised under the comments.
